# Ekde kiam oni celebras Esperanto-Tagon / Tago de Esperanto (26-a de julio)? Since when is Esperanto Day (July 26) being observed?

Tags: culture, history, festo

[Esperanto-Tago / Tago de Esperanto](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperantotago) en la 26-a julio memorigas [evento de la jaro 1887](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unua_Libro#Dato_de_eldono). Sed ekde kiam oni celebras ĝin en tiu dato? En kiu jaro oni unue festis aŭ aktivis pri ĝi?

---

[Esperanto Day on July 26](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto-Tag) commemorates an [event in the year 1887](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unua_Libro#History). But since when is it being observed at that date? In what year has it first been celebrated or been used for Esperanto-related activism?

Comment: The posters on http://www.linguistic-rights.org/esperanto-tago/ go back to [2015](http://www.linguistic-rights.org/esperanto-tago/esperanto-tago-2015.html). Was Esperanto Day a thing already before then?

Answer (score 1):

Mi trovis tiun-ĉi artikolon pri Esperanto-Tago kiu diras ke origine la nomo de la tago estis "Tago de la unua libro."

> [Dum longa tempo tiu tago estas konata kiel Tago de la Unua Libro, sed
> dum la lastaj jardekoj ĝi akiris novan nomon: Esperanto-tago.](https://uea.facila.org/artikoloj/movado/esperanto-tago-r244/)

Ĝi ne specifas jaron kiam ĝi ŝanĝis sian nomon, sed mi ankaŭ trovis [dokumenton en "Googlaj Libroj"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Esperanto_Magazine/R5lJAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) kiu parolis pri Esperanto-tago en [1915 en ĵurnalo de "Amerika Esperantisto"](https://books.google.com/books/content?id=R5lJAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA3-PA16&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U2u3MgYGwIh45p0pPqENskHkO6_Bg&ci=99%2C754%2C393%2C242&edge=0)

> Laŭ la “Faktlibro", presita kaj dissendata de la Ekspozicia Kompanio
> , sabaton, la 28an de Aŭgusto, oni festos kiel “Esperanto Tago" ĉe la
> Ekspozicio. Je tiu tago ĉiu Kongresano povos senpage eniri la
> Ekspozicion.  Granda demonstracio de Esperanto okazos en tiu tago, kaj
> la vespero estos pasigata sur la “Zono," tiu senegala strato de
> amuzaĵoj kaj distraĵoj provizita je kosto de preskaŭ 25 milionoj da
> spesmiloj.

[Kaj tiuj ĉi pri Ekspozicio, la 28-a de augusto de 1915:](https://books.google.com/books/content?id=R5lJAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA4-PA6&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U0uzmZMfDNy6sNj9SdNoE3mgBgO5A&ci=514%2C723%2C396%2C96&edge=0)

> Saturday August 28:
> ESPERANTO TAGO ĉe la Ekspozicio 9.00 AM to 11.00 PM
> on Grounds.

Ni bezonas esplori pli pri tiu ĉi tago pro respondi pli bone vian demandon.

Comment: Dankon por la esplorado. Ĉu vi ligis la ĝustajn bildojn? Ili (https://books.google.com/books/content?id=R5lJAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA3-PA16&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U2u3MgYGwIh45p0pPqENskHkO6_Bg&ci=99%2C754%2C393%2C242&edge=0 kaj https://books.google.com/books/content?id=R5lJAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA4-PA6&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U0uzmZMfDNy6sNj9SdNoE3mgBgO5A&ci=514%2C723%2C396%2C96&edge=0) montras aliajn tekstojn ol la citaĵojn.

Comment: Ĝi montras la tekstojn.  https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Esperanto_Magazine/R5lJAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0  montras la citaĵojn.